# Javascript HTML Audio repeats play function when only called once

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have the below function that is part of a bigger function but I eliminated all of the parts that aren't part of the problem.

The function creates an audio tag and puts it in the body. I'm using this method instead of the audio API because I'm using `createMediaElementSource` which requires the HTML element.

After the `ended` event is finished and you click the `replay` button, the `play` function is called twice, despite only being triggered once.

I tried putting the code in a snippet, but I couldn't duplicate the problem so I had to put it in a fiddle instead. - https://jsfiddle.net/6n2f34eh/

On the full function, there is user interaction that activates the playing.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-replay">REPLAY</button>

var func = function() {
  that = this;
  that.sound;

  this.init = function() {
    document.querySelector(".btn-replay").addEventListener("click", that.play);
    tag = document.createElement("audio");
    tag.className = "player";
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
    that.sound = document.querySelector(".player");
    that.sound.src = 'https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/CantinaBand3.wav';
    that.sound.addEventListener("canplaythrough", this.play);
    that.sound.addEventListener("ended", this.ended);
  }

  this.ended = function() {
    console.log("ended")
  }

  this.play = function() {
    console.log("play")
    that.sound.play();
  }

  this.init();

}

test = new func();
```

Comment: Code look awful, but seem to work. No need for `that` since `this` within a constructor method is the `new` instance, with the exception your EventListener function *(do like .addEventListener('click', ()=>{ this.play(); })*. Also, no need to get an Element that you have created with `document.createElement`... for example `this.sound = tag` would work. Honestly, I find this constructor rather useless, since the AudioElement has a `.play()` method.

Comment: "I'm using this method instead of the audio API because I'm using createMediaElementSource which requires the HTML element" and why are you using createMediaElementSource? Just use AudioBuffers, less pain.

Comment: @Kaiido, I'm using `createMediaElementSource` so I can use `StereoPannerNode` to control which speaker the sound comes out out.

Comment: So you really don't need a MediaElementSource, decaudeAudioData() your media and connect an AudioBufferSource to your pannernodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two event listeners that result in the play function being called - "click" on the button and "canplaythrough" on the sound. Right after you click the button, the audio loads from the link so both events are fired.